# How to extract confidence intervals from modeltime recursive ensembles?

Tags: r, time-series, confidence-interval, ensemble-learning, tidymodels

As I want to produce some visualizations and analysis on forecasted data outside the modeltime framework, I need to extract confidence values, fitted values and maybe also residuals.

The documentation indicates, that I need to use the function modeltime_calibrate() to get the confidence values and residuals. So one question would be, where do I extract the fitted values from?

My main question is whatsoever, how to do calibration on recursive ensembles. For any non-ensemble model I was able to do it, but in case of recursive ensembles I encounter some error messages, if I want to calibrate.

To illustrate the problem, look at the example code below, which ends up failing to calibrate all models:

```
library(modeltime.ensemble)
library(modeltime)
library(tidymodels)
library(earth)
library(glmnet)
library(xgboost)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(timetk)


FORECAST_HORIZON <- 24

m4_extended <- m4_monthly %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  future_frame(
    .length_out = FORECAST_HORIZON,
    .bind_data  = TRUE
  ) %>%
  ungroup()

lag_transformer_grouped <- function(data){
  data %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    tk_augment_lags(value, .lags = 1:FORECAST_HORIZON) %>%
    ungroup()
}

m4_lags <- m4_extended %>%
  lag_transformer_grouped()

test_data <- m4_lags %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  slice_tail(n = 12) %>%
  ungroup()

train_data <- m4_lags %>%
  drop_na()

future_data <- m4_lags %>%
  filter(is.na(value))

model_fit_glmnet <- linear_reg(penalty = 1) %>%
  set_engine("glmnet") %>%
  fit(value ~ ., data = train_data)

model_fit_xgboost <- boost_tree("regression", learn_rate = 0.35) %>%
  set_engine("xgboost") %>%
  fit(value ~ ., data = train_data)

recursive_ensemble_panel <- modeltime_table(
  model_fit_glmnet,
  model_fit_xgboost
) %>%
  ensemble_weighted(loadings = c(4, 6)) %>%
  recursive(
    transform  = lag_transformer_grouped,
    train_tail = panel_tail(train_data, id, FORECAST_HORIZON),
    id         = "id"
  )

model_tbl <- modeltime_table(
  recursive_ensemble_panel
)

calibrated_mod <- model_tbl %>%
  modeltime_calibrate(test_data, id = "id", quiet = FALSE)

model_tbl %>%
  modeltime_forecast(
    new_data    = future_data,
    actual_data = m4_lags,
    keep_data   = TRUE
  ) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  plot_modeltime_forecast(
    .interactive        = FALSE,
    .conf_interval_show = TRUE,
    .facet_ncol         = 2
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do some experimentation to find the right way to extract what I need (confidence intervals and residuals).

As you can see from the example code below, there needs to be a change in the models workflow to achieve this. Recursion needs to appear in the workflow object definition and neither in the model nor in the ensemble fit/specification.

I still have to do some tests here, but I guess, that I got what I need now:

```
# Time Series ML
library(tidymodels)
library(modeltime)
library(modeltime.ensemble)

# Core
library(tidyverse)
library(timetk)


# data def
FORECAST_HORIZON <- 24

lag_transformer_grouped <- function(m750){
  m750 %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    tk_augment_lags(value, .lags = 1:FORECAST_HORIZON) %>%
    ungroup()
}

m750_lags <- m750 %>%
  lag_transformer_grouped()

test_data <- m750_lags %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  slice_tail(n = 12) %>%
  ungroup()

train_data <- m750_lags %>%
  drop_na()

future_data <- m750_lags %>%
  filter(is.na(value))

# rec
recipe_spec <- recipe(value ~ date, train_data) %>%
  step_timeseries_signature(date) %>%
  step_rm(matches("(.iso$)|(.xts$)")) %>%
  step_normalize(matches("(index.num$)|(_year$)")) %>%
  step_dummy(all_nominal()) %>%
  step_fourier(date, K = 1, period = 12)

recipe_spec %>% prep() %>% juice()

# elnet 
model_fit_glmnet <- linear_reg(penalty = 1) %>%
  set_engine("glmnet") 

wflw_fit_glmnet <- workflow() %>%
  add_model(model_fit_glmnet) %>%
  add_recipe(recipe_spec %>% step_rm(date)) %>%
  fit(train_data) %>%
  recursive(
    transform  = lag_transformer_grouped,
    train_tail = panel_tail(train_data, id, FORECAST_HORIZON),
    id         = "id"
  )

# xgboost    
model_fit_xgboost <- boost_tree("regression", learn_rate = 0.35) %>%
  set_engine("xgboost")

wflw_fit_xgboost <- workflow() %>%
  add_model(model_fit_xgboost) %>%
  add_recipe(recipe_spec %>% step_rm(date)) %>%
  fit(train_data) %>%
  recursive(
    transform  = lag_transformer_grouped,
    train_tail = panel_tail(train_data, id, FORECAST_HORIZON),
    id         = "id"
  )

# mtbl
m750_models <- modeltime_table(
  wflw_fit_xgboost,
  wflw_fit_glmnet
)

# mfit
ensemble_fit <- m750_models %>%
 ensemble_average(type = "mean")

# mcalib
calibration_tbl <- modeltime_table(
  ensemble_fit
) %>%
  modeltime_calibrate(test_data)

# residuals
calib_out <- calibration_tbl$.calibration_data[[1]] %>% 
  left_join(test_data %>% select(id, date, value))


# Forecast ex post
ex_post_obj <- 
calibration_tbl %>%
  modeltime_forecast(
    new_data    = test_data,
    actual_data = m750
  )


# Forecast ex ante
data_prepared_tbl <- bind_rows(train_data, test_data)

future_tbl <- data_prepared_tbl %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  future_frame(.length_out = "2 years") %>%
  ungroup()

ex_ante_obj <- 
  calibration_tbl %>%
  modeltime_forecast(
    new_data    = future_tbl,
    actual_data = m750
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your `recursive_ensemble_panel`. You have to do the recursive part on the models themselves and not the ensemble. Like you I would have expected to do the recursive in one go, maybe via `modeltime_table`.

```
# start of changes to your code.

# added recursive to the model 
model_fit_glmnet <- linear_reg(penalty = 1) %>%
  set_engine("glmnet") %>%
  fit(value ~ ., data = train_data) %>% 
  recursive(
    transform  = lag_transformer_grouped,
    train_tail = panel_tail(train_data, id, FORECAST_HORIZON),
    id         = "id"
  )

# added recursive to the model     
model_fit_xgboost <- boost_tree("regression", learn_rate = 0.35) %>%
  set_engine("xgboost") %>%
  fit(value ~ ., data = train_data) %>% 
  recursive(
    transform  = lag_transformer_grouped,
    train_tail = panel_tail(train_data, id, FORECAST_HORIZON),
    id         = "id"
  )

# removed recursive part    
recursive_ensemble_panel <- modeltime_table(
  model_fit_glmnet,
  model_fit_xgboost
) %>%
  ensemble_weighted(loadings = c(4, 6))

# rest of your code
```

Comment: I just embedded your code into mine and took the calibration object as input for modeltime_forecast(). However, looking into the calibration or forecast object I can find the columns conf_hi and conf_lo, but no confidence values, as the columns contain NA only. Did you check for the values, after completing the code?

Comment: Everyting I use on your example results in NA's in the confidence columns, whether I take only model_fit_xgboost without recursive, no ensemble etc etc. Following the examples in the vignettes everything works. Not sure where the issue, but you will have to go through the differences between what the examples show and where your code fails.

Comment: Maybe worth asking this question on the github page of the package/

Comment: No need. I will post my solution soon